# Asynchronous await In Node.js

Tags: node.js, async-await

How to use the asynchronous Await in Node.js by using these function and how
The request.get() function returns a Promise by which user will await...

I have tried the Below code so far and also gave the explanation below

```
async function fun1(req, res){
  let response = await request.get('http://localhost:3000');
    if (response.err) { console.log('error');}
    else { console.log('fetched response');
}
```

The code above basically asks the javascript engine running the code to wait for the request.get() function to complete before moving on to the next line to execute it. The request.get() function returns a Promise for which user will await . Before async/await, if it needs to be made sure that the functions are running in the desired sequence, that is one after the another, chain them one after the another or register callbacks.

Comment: post some code, what you've tried so far

Comment: What do you exactly mean with asynchronous await? Await by default waits till the other task is done, but you can still run other code just fine.

Comment: I have tried the Below code so far and also gave the explanation below....

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
async function fun1(req, res){
  let response = await request.get('http://localhost:3000');
    if (response.err) { console.log('error');}
    else { console.log('fetched response');
}
```

Comment: The code above basically asks the javascript engine running the code to wait for the request.get() function to complete before moving on to the next line to execute it. The request.get() function returns a Promise for which user will await . Before async/await, if it needs to be made sure that the functions are running in the desired sequence, that is one after the another, chain them one after the another or register callbacks.

Answer (score -1):

`request` package does not use return promise. Use the `request-promise` package which wraps the `request` with `Promise`.

You can use it like:

```
const rp = require('request-promise')

async function getSomeData() {
  try {
    const url = 'http://some.com'
    // waits for promise to resolve
    const data = await rp(url)
    // data contains resolved value if successfull
    // continue some other stuff
    ...
  } catch (e) {
    // handle error if error occurred
    console.error(e)
  }
}
```